# Moving object with changing radius

Tags: animation

I want to animate a Skateboard and it's movements.
I have found a formula for the radius compared with the "lean angle". The "Lean angle" is how much the board turns, however, it is always changing.

[image]

When it moves forward, is there a way to set a radius of a turn compared to the turning of the board?

Or is there a easier solution?